# How to make href will work on button in IE8

Tags: html, xhtml, internet-explorer-8

I want `href` will work on `type="button"`in IE8.

```
<a href="submit.php"><input type="button" value="Submit" class="button" /></a>
```

Other browser working fine but on IE8 the code above not working. How to fix it?

**Update**

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post"">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
</form>
```

I know this way can be done. But **I want to know other ways** how to make it work on IE8 without to have the `<form></form>`

Comment: why don´t you use submit button instead of using button?

Comment: yes can be done.. but i want to know how to make it work on IE without to have the form submit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

onclick="window.location=this.parentNode.href;"/>

this.parentNode can refer to a tag so... it should work or test getAttribute even

Comment: It's not the 90s. Never never never use onclick.

Answer (score 1):

why not use

```
<form action="submit.php" method="get">
<input type="button" value="Submit" class="button" />
</form>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I used to be all happy that IE8 was not IE6. But seriously.

I'm using jQuery to patch up any button tag within an `<a>` link tag, inside conditional tags so it's just for old IEs.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>

<script type="text/javascript">
// IE8 is the new IE6. Patch up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949910/how-to-make-href-will-work-on-button-in-ie8
$('button').click(function(){
    document.location = $(this).parents('a').first().prop('href');
});
</script>

<![endif]-->
```