# efficient way of checking which class is clicked using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know the most efficient and good practice on accomplishing the following. The case is simple: if you click prev link decrease pagenum or increment if you click next link.Then send it to a function along with its parent data.

I know how to do this by doing two different function for on, but i want a simple, and faster approach.

Html:

```
 <div>
      hello world
    <a class="prevpg>Previous</a>
    <a class="nextpg">Next</a>
   </div>
```

javascript:

```
   $(document).on('click', '.prevpg, .nextpg', function(){
     var element = $(this).parent('div').text();  
//    if ,prevpg was clicked
        somefunction(pagenum--, element)
//    else if .nextpg clicked
       somefunction(pagenum++,element)
    })



 function somefunction(pagenum, data ){
  var test = true; 
  if(data == 'hello world'){
     test = false; }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'search',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {'pagenumber':pagenum, testdata: test} ,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(res){
            $('body').append(res.data);
     }
     });
    }
```

Comment: Typo on line 6, you mean `element` not `elment`.

Comment: why use the parent div? probably you could try if($(this).attr('class') === "prevpg")

Comment: everything in the html is dynamic. I need the content of the parent div to be passed into another function.

Comment: sry indentation was off, thats all. it was corrected.

Comment: @ravitadi Can you check and see if my answer solves your question.

Comment: @ravitadi Is the someFunction() mandatory or you can embed the function code into the event handler code.

Comment: @ravitadi Edited the answer. Can you check it now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

```
  $(document).on('click', '.prevpg, .nextpg', function(){
     var element = $(this).parent('div').text();  
      // When prevpg was clicked
      if($(this).hasClass("prevpg")){
        somefunction(pagenum--, element)
      }
     else{
      // When nextpg was clicked
       somefunction(pagenum++,element)
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

In this code, there is typo:

```
 <div id="results">
  hello world
<a class=".prevpg">Previous</a>
<a class=".nextpg">Next</a>
```

correct it to:

```
<a class="prevpg">Previous</a> //remove "." for class names
```

Now for actual question you can know which class was clicked by using:

```
$(this).hasClass("prevpg");
```

Make use of `switch` or `else if` ladder to invoke the appropriate function if you have more than 2 conditions to check. For your code only 2 cases hence `if else` will do.

```
$(document).on('click', '.prevpg, .nextpg', function(){
 var element = $(this).parent('div').text();  
 if($(this).hasClass("prevpg"))
    somefunction(pagenum--, element)
 else
   somefunction(pagenum++,element)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example demonstrating with inline onClick events.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  hello world
  <a class="prevpg" onClick="someFunction('prev', this)">Previous</a>
  <a class="nextpg" onClick="someFunction('next', this)">Next</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function somefunction(action, el) {

    if(action == 'prev') pagenum--;
    else pagenum++;

    var data = $(el).parent('div').text();

    // AJAX call
}
```

**EDIT** (Only JS Solution)

```
$('.prevpg, .nextpg').on('click', function(){

    if($(this).attr('class') == 'prevpg') pagenum--;
    else pagenum++;

    var data = $(this).parent('div').text();

    // AJAX call
    // If you need some function call it like this
    // someFunction(pagenum, data);
});
```

Comment: dont use inline javascript, because of different behaviour in different browsers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Script Shiva. Great answer, unfortunately, for my case the html is dynamic (made by javascript) so it won't work..

Comment: @FUserThrowError Can you explain it please? I don't find any difference for a simple onClick in any browsers. They are all working the same.

Comment: checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002690/why-inline-javascript-is-bad

Comment: @FUserThrowError I accept your link, but in this case this code is present only in this page as well as only at two places in a page. There is no maintainability issues clearly. And I don't see any browser compatibility as you stated in your link. Anyway thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your html/code, I've cleaned them up and added the answer.

I also assumed you intend to get the value `"hello world"`, instead of `"hello world Previous Next"`

HTML

```
<div id="results">
    hello world
    <a class="prevpg">Previous</a>
    <a class="nextpg">Next</a>
</div>
```

js

```
pagenum = 0;

$(document).on('click', '.prevpg, .nextpg', function () {
    var element = $(this).parent('div').contents().first().text();
    if ($(this).hasClass('prevpg')) {
        pagenum--;
        somefunction(element);
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('nextpg')) {
        pagenum++;
        somefunction(element);
    }
});

function somefunction(data) {
    var test = !(data == 'hello world');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'search',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            'pagenumber': pagenum,
            testdata: test
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(res) {
            $('body').append(res.data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks @Samuel for your answer, Is this a good way of approaching to what i am trying to do?

Comment: i edited the question. Just trying to make a ajax call

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be possible done with this (using data-attributes)

```
<div>
  hello world
  <a class="control" data-move="-1">Previous</a>
  <a class="control" data-move="+1">Next</a>
</div>
```

And js

```
$(".control").on("click", function(e){
  var t_number = parseInt($(this).attr("data-move")),
      element  = $(this).parent('div').text();

  someFunction(total + t_number, $(this));
  return false;
});
```

If you are bind events to document use namespaces.

```
$(document).on("click.HANDLE_CLICK_LINK", .....);
```