# JS Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: makePicSmall is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

i made a function, which is called, when whenever someone clicks on one of the little pictures, as you can see in the picture below.
My functions, which are to be executed look like this:

```
function makePicSmall(giveString){
    if(firstTime){
        firstTime = NO;
        makePicBig(giveString);
    }else{
        $("#bigPic").animate({width:0, height: 0}, 1000);
        window.setTimeout(makePicBig(giveString,1000));
    }
}

function makePicBig(sourceString){
    document.getElementById("bigPic").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("bigPic").src = sourceString;

    $("#bigPic").animate({width:320, height: 586}, 3000);
}
```

My function is called like:

```
<a class="lilPic1Link" >
    <img src="resources/littleFlyingDoggScreen1.png" alt="Willkommen-Screen" width="52" height="93" id="lilPic1"    onClick="makePicSmall('resources/flyingDoggScreen1.PNG')">
</a>
<a class="lilPic2Link" >
    <img src="resources/littleFlyingDoggScreen2.png" alt="screen1" width="52" height="93" id="lilPic2" onClick="makePicSmall('resources/flyingDoggScreen2.PNG')">
</a>
<a class="lilPic3Link" >
    <img src="resources/littleFlyingDoggScreen3.png" alt="screen2" width="52" height="93" id="lilPic3" onClick="makePicSmall('resources/flyingDoggScreen3.PNG')">
</a>
```

But when I click on a little picture, I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: makePicSmall is not defined.

Here is a picture so you don´t have to imagine that stuff.
[image]

Why do I get this error? And how can I fix it?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's `Boolean firstTime = YES` doing there? its not JavaScript and will break subsequent valid code, you mean `var` perhaps?

Comment: you should start do quoting the string variable else use as boolean variable like true / false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `true` or `false` for booleans in Javascript, `YES` and `NO` are the Objective-C variants.

Change line 45 to

```
var firstTime = true;
```

and line 54 to

```
firstTime = false;
```

Also there's another error on line 58, you have a misplaced parentheses `)`

`makePicBig` only takes one argument. The `1000` belongs to the `setTimeout` function.

Finally, since we're being helpful, in the long term save yourself some headache and [avoid inline javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19002690/184646) by moving your js code in to separate js files.

Answer (score 1):

`firstTime` is not defined and assigned properly with quotes. add it in the window scope like below.

```
var firstTime;

function makePicSmall(giveString){
    if(firstTime){
        firstTime = 'NO';
        makePicBig(giveString);
    }
    else {
        $("#bigPic").animate({width:0, height: 0}, 1000);
        window.setTimeout(makePicBig(giveString), 1000);
    }
}
```

Note: if you want to check each firstTime click of the `img`. play with `data attributes` like below.

```
<img src="resources/littleFlyingDoggScreen1.png" 
data-first-time="no"
alt="Willkommen-Screen" width="52" height="93" 
id="lilPic1"
onClick="makePicSmall('resources/flyingDoggScreen1.PNG')">
```

Answer (score 0):

For the error on line 45:

```
var firstTime = true;
```

Because in javascript you can define every variable with var.
And I'm not quite sure but if you solve that problem then the other error shoudn't be displayed too because the function doesn't throw an error(because of the undefined variable).