# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" at the end of this line. Wondering what was the issue as I've checked the parentheses correctly.

```
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnInsert" value="Save" onclick="insertupdatedata('0',$('#txtCheckpoint').val(),$('#txtCheckpointDisplay).val(),'INSERT')" />
```

Comment: You omitted a single quote for `txtCheckpointDisplay`. So it should be `<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnInsert" value="Save" onclick="insertupdatedata('0',$('#txtCheckpoint').val(),$('#txtCheckpointDisplay').val(),'INSERT')" />` Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You omitted a single quote `'` for the `txtCheckpointDisplay` jQuery selector.

So it should be

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnInsert" value="Save" onclick="insertupdatedata('0',$('#txtCheckpoint').val(),$('#txtCheckpointDisplay').val(),'INSERT')" />
```

And as a side note, you'd better not to use the inline functions like onclick. Try to use `addEventListener('click', function(){})` or something like that for better practice. More about it, visit [Why inline JavaScript is bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002690/why-inline-javascript-is-bad)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

The "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" occurs when we make a syntax error when calling a function, e.g. forget to separate its arguments with a comma. To solve the error make sure to correct any syntax errors in the arguments list of the function invocation.