# Change the select text color based on option color

Tags: css

I want to display the selected option in the same colour as the option itself.

```html
<select>
  <option value="1" style="color:blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="2" style="color:red">Red</option>
</select>
```

The options are displayed correctly in blue and red colours, but once selected, they are black. Is it possible to display it in blue or red, matching the selected option?

PD: I know how to do it in JS, but I'm not sure if it could be done in CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with pure CSS with the `:has` pseudo class

```css
select:has(option[value="1"]:checked) {
  color: blue;
}
select:has(option[value="2"]:checked) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">Blue</option>
  <option value="2">Red</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `select` has `onchange` it can modify `dataset` equal to `value`. Then css can reflect that. If this is part of a larger application, remove `onchange` and implement an event listener in js file

```css
.blue,select[data-chosen='1']{
  color:blue;
}
.red,select[data-chosen='2']{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="this.dataset.chosen = this.value;" data-chosen="1">
  <option value="1" class="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="2" class="red">Red</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Stop using inline `on*` handlers like `onchange`. JS is supposed to be in one place only and that's its respective tag or file

Comment: Also, if you're using JavaScript anyway you may as well just use simple CSS and - one option - [CSS custom properties](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4remaz2q/), or possibly just directly [change the color with CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4remaz2q/1/).

Comment: @DavidThomas neither of those keep current styling, both change all options to the selected color

Comment: That's what I get for not testing in Chrome (as well as Firefox).

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan for the amount of js its not [horrible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19002885/3462319) if this is a larger application, separation would be better

Comment: Casually the HTML field is repainted with an AJAX request so I couldn't use the `onchange` event, because it would be fired and then refreshed.