# Internet explore button link not working

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to navigate backward to a file in the parent directory using a button as a link.

```
<a href="../index.php"><input type="button" value="Back"></a>
```

For some reason that code works on all the other browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, but it doesn't work in InternetExplorer.
So does anyone know why or is there some workaround?

Answer (score 0):

> So does anyone know why or is there some workaround?

You may try like this which may serve as a work around:

```
<input type="button" value="google.com" onClick="javascript:location.href = 'http://google.com';" />
```

Also check out [`<button>` not working in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062061/button-not-working-in-ie8)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i decided to use a regular link with some css styling.

Comment: @Adrao:- How about this: `<a href="../index.php" class="button">Learn more</a>` ?